# Object not received in Backend POST method as sent through $.ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

The problem is that I am sending an object array in correct format through $4.ajax to a POST method in MVC, but on the backend it is not receiving as expected. If I send an Array of 3 objects, it shows that the backend object is received as a List of 3 objects, but the attributes in those objects are not loaded properly. Infact, none of the values are copied.

Here is the relevant javascript code

```
        var array = new Array();

        for (var i = 0 ; i < $('.TourCommission:enabled').length; i++)
        {
            var data = {
                TourCodeID: parseInt($('.TourCommission:enabled').eq(i).parent().prev().html()),
                Commission: parseFloat($('.TourCommission:enabled').eq(i).val())
            };
            array.push(data);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Booking/submitAgentTourCommissions',
            data: JSON.stringify(array),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $('form').submit();
            },
            error: function () {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Here is the backend code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult submitAgentTourCommissions(List<AgentTourCommission> obj) {
    return Json(true);
}
```

The AgentTourCommission class is as below

```
public class AgentTourCommission
{
    public int UserID;
    public string UserName;
    public int TourCodeID;
    public string TourCodeName;
    public float Commission;
}
```

screenshot of Javascript Watch

[image]

screenshot of BackEnd Watch

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add the `get set` like this:

```
    public class AgentTourCommission
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int TourCodeID { get; set; }
        public string TourCodeName { get; set; }
        public float Commission { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope you help!

Comment: Thank you Nacho, your answer was delicious. It was such a silly mistake.